# How to get the identity of the storing peers in IPFS private network?

Tags: javascript, go, ethereum, ipfs, decentralized-applications

We are building a Decentralized Storage Renting System using IPFS and we want to get the peers who are storing the chunks after adding a file in the network?

Is there any method that can provide us with any information or addresses of the storing nodes?